# Find the file system location of an installed NodeJS module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm looking at the below code from the [grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul](https://github.com/maenu/grunt-template-jasmine-istanbul/blob/master/src/main/js/template.js#L14-L15) project on GitHub;

```
var DEFAULT_TEMPLATE = __dirname + '/../../../../grunt-contrib-jasmine/tasks/'
                       + 'jasmine/templates/DefaultRunner.tmpl';
```

I've noticed before that you can (not that you necessarily should) require internals from a NodeJS module like so;

```
console.log(require('grunt/package.json'));
```

But in this case the file is an Underscore.js template, so you can't require it.

Is there a way to find the install location (which can differ) of an npm module in order to harden this a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require.resolve(moduleName)

should do the trick for locally installed node_modules